# Use variable as jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to use a variable as a jQuery selector but it outputs an error in console:

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: # in jquery.2.1.4.min.js

Does anyone have an explanation why this would happen?

```
function FileSelected(file) {
    var imgId = RoxyUtils.GetUrlParam('img');
    $(window.parent.document).find("#" + imgId).attr('src', file.fullPath);
    $(window.parent.document).find("#" + imgId).next().val(file.fullPath);
    window.parent.closeCustomRoxy();
}
```

Comment: what is teh value of `imgId`

Comment: try adding the hashtag while defining the variable `var imgId= "#"+RoxyUtils.GetUrlParam('img');`. Also, please `console.log(imgId);` right after defining it, and let us know what you see.

Comment: the id attr of img. for example: "img1" .

Comment: only `.find('#')` gives that error in my console, so I assume `imgId` is blank, null, etc.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didnt see this comment by BenG. I posted similar answer

Answer (score 0):

If you can change:

```
var imgId = '#' + RoxyUtils.GetUrlParam('img').toString(); //append # in the image ID, and change to string, if returning an integer.
$(window.parent.document).find(imgId).attr('src', file.fullPath);
$(window.parent.document).find(imgId).next().val(file.fullPath);
```

Then, it should work.

Let me know

Answer (score 0):

Just added a if else to make sure the imgId is not empty.

```
function FileSelected(file) {
            var imgId = RoxyUtils.GetUrlParam('img');
            if(imgId.trim().length >0){
                   $(window.parent.document).find("#" + imgId).attr('src', file.fullPath);
                   $(window.parent.document).find("#" + imgId).next().val(file.fullPath);
                   window.parent.closeCustomRoxy();
            }
            else{
              console.log("the value of imgId is : " + imgId);
            }           
        }
```

Make sure your imgId does not have a '#' in its value.

Answer (score -1):

Use the context-parameter, can you try using below way....

```js
function FileSelected(file){
 /**
 * file is an object containing following properties:
 * 
 * fullPath - path to the file - absolute from your site root 
*/
 var imgId= RoxyUtils.GetUrlParam('img');
 $("#"+imgId,window.parent.document).attr('src', file.fullPath);
 $("#"+imgId,window.parent.document).next().val(file.fullPath);

 window.parent.closeCustomRoxy();
}
```